# From input check, check conditions and based on conditions, give result in output cell

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have following data: Column A has many items and column B has respective Quantity. Below is just 4 items for example. In column 3 I am interested in total boxes in which this quantity will fill.

```
| Item | Quantity(Q) |
|------|-------------|
| A    | 1200        |
| B    | 12345       |
| C    | 23          |
| D    | 4           |
```

Also I have following info:Which tells you Number of boxes that will accomodate the quantity. First row tells if item quantity is more than 120, boxes needed will be INT(Q/120) as each box capacity is 120. We have 4 boxes with capacity 120, 100, 50 and 25 respectively.

```
| Total Quantity | Total Boxes required |
|----------------|----------------------|
| Q>120          | (INT(Q/120)+1)       |
| 100<Q<120      | (INT(Q/100)+1)       |
| 50<Q<100       | (INT(Q/50)+1)        |
| 25<Q<50        | (INT(Q/25)+1)        |
| 12<Q<25        | 0.8                  |
| 6<Q<12         | 0.6                  |
| Otherwise      | 0.4                  |
```

Now I want a simpler way (without multiple if) to check the quantity. if it is greater than 120, all can fit in 120 size box. If the quantity is greater than 100 but less than 120, it can fit in two 100 size box and so on. Can you help with one simple formula to check quantity, compare against the second table and show result based on condition is 2nd table. Similar like switch function in C? I

Comment: Hi Vikas, I understood your query. But what i dont understand is how does this table will be in Excel file?Is it Possible to share that data(Like how exactlty it will be in excel)

Comment: that will result in `2` for all `25<Q<239` ?

Comment: Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort?

Answer (score 0):

Because your formula will result in `2` when Q is from 25 to 239, it can be simplified to

```
= IF( $B2 < 240, LOOKUP( $B2, { 0, 6, 12, 25; 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 2 } ), INT( $B2 / 120 ) + 1 )
```